# Controlling parent window after link (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, popup, window, parent

I'm using a form handling service which after hitting submit links to an intermediate page before using setTimeout() to link back to my original page. I would like to cover the ugly intermediate page with something nicer. So far I've tried having the submit button load a new window onClick, where the new window uses parent.write to open a div that would cover the entire page and allow me to write my own html. The problem with that is that it prevents the intermediate page from loading at all, and thus prevents my forms from being processed.

My current workaround involves using setTimeout() in the child window to load my own page immediately after the intermediate page is loaded. It works, but I still see the intermediate page first.

Please help me!

Comment: Do you have any code or a fiddle?

Comment: that old four letter word: ajax springs to mind. It'll allow you to submit the form without the need of an intermediate page, which is a far more elegant solution than linking back and forth at any rate

Comment: it's a page i made for work which allows us to input info to the 6 different sites we use from one page. it's just to make things more convenient and keep track of who's doing what we are using a free host that doesnt support server-size scripting like ajax and a free form processing service called emailmeform which is why we are directed to an intermediate page. i've added a lot of javascript to try and hide/clean up the page but this is what i have so far, feel free to check it out. if you plan on hitting submit please use the name "TEST" when it prompts you. http://customertrack.host-ed.me/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

switched to 000webhost and wrote my own formhandler